# Select / Merge user specific rows with additional fallback rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

Setup: Postgresql table with a *customer_id* and a *request_id* column (+ additional not relevant data). 
The rows with *customer_id* set to *NULL* work as a fallback/default.

Example what the table looks like:

[image: Example]

Goal: I want to select all rows from the table for a given customer (e.g. where *customer_id* = 2).

For any existent *request_id*: If there are no entries for the given customer, return the fallback rows (where customer is null).

So the result should look like this:

[image: example goal]

Any idea how to write the select statement for postgresql? I'm kind of stuck and couldn't really find anything helpful so far. Thanks!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange requirement.

```
select t.*
from t
where t.customer_id = 2 or
      (t.customer_id is null and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.request_id = t.request_id and t2.customer_id = 2)
      );
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `(request_id, customer_id)`.

Comment: Thank you, this does work, but is very slow (takes 1 to 3 seconds on my local db - compared to 4ms for a select * from t). Any way to optimize it?

What is so strange about it? The way we handle default/fallback values? We were trying not to copy all the default values to each customer on create.